# Changing rows to specific order

Tags: bash, sed, awk, row

I have this file data.txt:

```
 value1
 value2
 value3
 A
 value4
 value5
 value6
 B
 value7
 value8
 value9
 C
 .
 .
 .
```

how can I create this output in bash:

```
 A
 value1
 value2
 value3
 B
 value4
 value5
 value6
 C
 value7
 value8
 value9
 .
 .
 .
```

change the positions of letters, the file extend to Z and all the values are differents.

Edit:
 Here is a bin of real data, real_input.txt:

```
 1.688390 2.089450 2.499110
 1.931510 2.840060 1.269530
 2.002690 0.698842 3.072450
 1.612190 0.748615 1.891070
 1.344360 1.131220 0.599143
 1.804060 0.953536 1.510170
 0.597634 2.260670 1.140460
 E = -1173.43219915
 1.673696 2.069325 2.475855
 1.912555 2.814333 1.257740
 1.985098 0.693024 3.043875
 1.584818 0.751690 1.867771
 1.294662 1.088698 0.575066
 1.774873 0.934282 1.501254
 0.604104 2.229057 1.124296
 E = -1173.43450443
 1.650579 2.040808 2.440887
 1.885902 2.775145 1.239654
 1.957682 0.683252 3.002345
 1.534811 0.761264 1.827162
 1.199689 1.007516 0.529033
 1.721899 0.898366 1.489224
 0.619975 2.172922 1.095319
 E = -1173.43870135
 .
 .
 .
```

and so on.

Comment: yes, all the values are numbers.

Comment: Are the labels actually named like that, or are there always 3 lines followed by a label?

Comment: The original label is a string, here an example: E=-1173.45.
There are always N lines followed by a label (in this example N=3).

Comment: Show some actual sample data, not just a format/layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are always 3 lines between labels (sets of 4) try:

```
sed -n 'N;N;h;n;p;g;p' file
```

for a variable solution, you could try:

```
awk '!(NR%n){print $0 p; p=x; next}{p=p ORS $0}' n=4 file
```

Comment: and the second solution adapt excellent to my specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!{N;s/^(.*)\n(\s*[A-Z])$/\2\n\1/;Ta}' file
```

This slurps in lines until it encounters a marker, then re-arranges the lines, prints them out and so on.

An alternative:

```
sed '/^\s*[A-Z]$/!{H;b};G;s/\n//p;z;x;z' file
```

Comment: thank you, the first solution works perfect, the second doesn't works.

Answer (score 1):

If **`awk`** is acceptable then this should work:

```
awk '
!/=/ { line[++cnt]=$0; next }
{ print $0
  for(i=1;i<=cnt;i++) {
      print line[i]
  }
  cnt=0; delete line
}' file
```

or a **`gnu-sed`** solution:

```
sed -n '/=/!{H;b};p;s/.*//;x;s/\n//;p' file
```

Comment: this script is not working for me in the example data.txt. The output is equal to input, I can't realize where is the problem. I have GNU Awk 3.1.8.

Comment: @AlejoBernardin Have updated the solution based on your sample data. Both should works for variable number of lines.

Comment: Thank you @jaypal!, now both solutions works perfect ;)

Comment: @AlejoBernardin You're welcome. The sample data you show in your question should be true representation of your real data. We would have saved a lot of time debugging with incorrect data set. `:)`. Good luck!

Comment: yes, the next time I'll put immediately the true data. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in $(cat value)
do
  if [[ $(echo $i | grep -v '^[0-9]*$' | wc -l) == 1 ]]
  then
     echo "$i$x" | tr '#' '\n'
     x=""
  else 
     x="$x#$i"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an all BASH solution.

```
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line != [A-Z] ]]; then
        str+=("$line")
    else
        echo "$line"
        printf "%s\n" "${str[@]}"
        str=()
    fi
done < data.txt
```

Comment: You can replace the for loop with: `printf "%s\n" "${str[@]}"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the input file I made from OP's description for testing.

```
$ cat file
121413232
12321313
123123213
3423
E=-1173.45
23234324
24534545
23423424
B=323.332
43324
234234254
4354543
X=-2323.23
```

Use gnu sed ( no care of fix line numbers)

```
sed -r ':a;$!{N;s/(.*)\n([^0-9].*)/\2\n\1/;Ta}' file
```